# "Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'" (+ more)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently trying to create a chrome extension. For some reason, I get an error for seemingly no reason. (See title)

The HTML popup code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en_NZ">

<body>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <button id="checkbox"></button>
    <script src="sripts/settings.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The settings.js code:

```
document.getElementById("checkbox").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("hello")
});
```

I'm not even too sure what the exact issue is. Sometimes the extensions page highlights the `</body>` , and sometimes it highlights the `<button id="checkbox"></button>` , and sometimes it highlights the `</head>` .

Can anyone help with this? Thanks.

Comment: You may see errors that occurred earlier. Please install again after uninstalling. If the error still occurs, please post the error screen capture and manifest.json.

Comment: Please post your `manifest.json` That's the first thing people should post when asking about extension programming. Also, it would be great if you could post the "(+ more)" from your error message. Because more is more.

Comment: 1) Click the `Clear all` button to remove the old irrelevant errors. 2) Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.